# How can I obtain the IPv4 address of the client?

Tags: unix, sockets

I'm prepping for a simple work project and am trying to familiarize myself with the basics of socket programming in a Unix dev environment.  At this point, I have some basic server side code setup to listen for incoming TCP connection requests from clients after the parent socket has been created and is set to listen...

```
int sockfd, newfd;    
unsigned int len;
socklen_t sin_size;
char msg[]="Test message sent";
char buf[MAXLEN];
int st, rv;
struct addrinfo hints, *serverinfo, *p; 
struct sockaddr_storage client;
char ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

.
. //parent socket creation and listen code omitted for simplicity
.

//wait for connection requests from clients
while(1)
  {
    //Returns the socketID and address of client connecting to socket
    if( ( newfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &len) ) == -1 ){
      perror("Accept");
      exit(-1);
    }

    if( (rv = recv(newfd, buf, MAXLEN-1, 0 )) == -1) {
      perror("Recv");
      exit(-1);
    }
    struct sockaddr_in *clientAddr = ( struct sockaddr_in *) get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&client);
    inet_ntop(client.ss_family, clientAddr, ip, sizeof ip);
    printf("Receive from %s: query type is %s\n", ip, buf);

    if( ( st = send(newfd, msg, strlen(msg), 0)) == -1 ) {
      perror("Send");
      exit(-1);
    }

    //ntohs is used to avoid big-endian and little endian compatibility issues
    printf("Send %d byte to port %d\n", ntohs(clientAddr->sin_port) );

    close(newfd);
  }

}
```

I found the `get_in_addr` function online and placed it at the top of my code and use it to obtain the IP address of the client connecting...

```
// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
  if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
    return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
  }

  return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}
```

but the function always returns the IPv6 IP address since thats what the `sa_family` property is set as.

My question is, is the IPv4 IP address stored anywhere in the data I'm using and, if so, how can I access it?

Thanks so much in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're getting an IPv6 address, then that's what the client is using to connect. There isn't a 1-1 correspondence between IPv6 and IPv4 addresses, nor between IP addresses and client devices.

Its a bit like saying you've received an email from someone, but you're having trouble working out their postal address from their email address.

Comment: I thought that might be the case.  Thanks for the clarification, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

See [The need for a "getipv4addr" and "getipv6addr" function](http://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/coding/articles/unix/the-need-for-a-getipv4addr-and-getipv6addr-function) article on my website. It describes how you can obtain the IPv4 or IPv6 address of the computer on which it is running.

Answer (score 0):

While you are physically getting an IPv6 address, if the client connected with IPv4 then the address will in the [IPv4-mapped address format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_addresses).

You can extract the IPv4 portion of the address by accessing bytes 12, 13, 14 and 15 of `s6_addr`.